# Scooter clutch plate gets damaged/burn't for a short time

Tags: clutch, gears, scooter, clutch-cylinder, bajaj

I have an Indian Scooter (**Bajaj Chetak**) which was bought 15 years ago.   For the last few days, the scooter has been witnessing lot of problems.

**1. The clutch plate gets damaged and burn't** - It has been more than 10 times the clutch plate has been replaced but to my vain I haven't found one mechanic who could solve this problem.
Some mechanics suggested for replacing the complete clutch kit, but nothing worked.
**2. The gear changes automatically without manual effort** - Suppose you are driving the scooter in 20 kmph and you accelerate to 40 kmph. Without manual effort gear changes automatically. What could be the reason.
As this scooter is not in production now, finding spare parts has become a needle in haystack.
**3. Scooter kicker pedal frees** - When the clutch plate gets damaged, the kick starter pedal frees with no action. When you try to kick start, it simply frees down. (This scooter does not have auto start feature)

**What is causing this problem?
How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

If your clutch is burning out so often, maybe it's slipping - check the adjustment of the clutch lever by loosening the locking nut and turning the adjustment (it should engage around halfway on the lever and by fully engaged before the lever is fully out).

The kick start may require the clutch to operate.

Answer (score -1):

I have similar issue with lambretta.
Kicker sometimes simply goes down as if clutch engaged.
I think it's the weak springs. Replace springs, clutch plates and pressure plates.